# Regex to match all patterns in a line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to scrape through some log files to find a line, such as this:

```
'A-Topeka-Firesale\:\s\*132\*\d{2,5}\*[23]\d{9}\#'
```

and once that line is matched, to go backward in the file and find a preceding line, like this:

```
2016-12-30 11:02:12 DEBUG[ispatcher-18269] ab.talk.this.api.Api - http://hostname:19991/trapeze?session_id=176764&manager_event=old&apostrophe=2341231231234&_operation=doc 3da48a90-0f4f-4eb3-a241-94a1f05b891b requesting:
```

and I need to match `"http://hostname:19991/trapeze?"`, `"manager_event=old"` and `requesting:` for the second line (which is usually between 3-5 lines above the first match, to be a match.

So far I have tried variations of this:

```
for each, line in enumerate(f):
first_match = re.search(b'A-Topeka-Firesale\:\s\*132\*\d{2,5}\*[23]\d{9}\#', line)     
    if first_match:
for i in range(each, -1, -1)
    if re.match("|".join(['http://hostname:19991/trapeze', 'manager_event=old', 'requesting:']), str(f[i])):
        break
```

and this:

```
for each, line in enumerate(f):
    first_match = re.search(b'A-Topeka-Firesale\:\s\*132\*\d{2,5}\*[23]\d{9}\#', line)     
        if first_match:
            for i in range(each, -1, -1)
                if all(re.match(regex_str, str(f[i])) for regex_str in ['http://hostname:19991/trapeze', 'manager_event=old', 'requesting: ']):
                break
```

And the call matches wrong lines (eg lines starting with blank spaces and with an instance of one of the matches (trapeze)).
Please what am I doing wrong and how can I do it better?

Sample input:

```
 2016-01-30 00:00:27 DEBUG[-dispatcher-411] ab.talk.this.api.Api - http://hostname:19991/trapeze?manager_id=40178&manager_event=old&apostrophe=2341231231234&_operation=doc dgfgdffb-8123-4f05-ac15-7ac841afad14 requesting:
  HEADERS:
  this-is-a-header: 200*01231231234
  A-Topeka-Firesale: *132*200*01231231234#
  Host: hostname:19991
  Accept: */*
  User-Agent: AHC/2.0
  Timeout-Access: <function1>
 CONTENT:

2015-03-12 00:00:28 DEBUG[-dispatcher-747] ab.talk.this.api.Api - http://hostname:19991/trapeze?manager_id=84942&manager_event=old&apostrophe=2341231231235&_operation=ogle abcdf8237-393f-4c4b-bc46-e184cbf08d9a requesting:
  HEADERS:
  this-is-a-header: 100
  A-Topeka-Firesale: *132*100#
  Host: hostname:19991
  Accept: */*
  User-Agent: AHC/2.0
  Timeout-Access: <function1>
 CONTENT:
```

Comment: can you post both lines (also the the preceding one?). Regex has lookahead matches which mean that you can boil it down to only one regex and don't need to store the last line in memory

Comment: Do you need the line with all 3 strings ? the regex string you have is in or statement.

Comment: I assume f is a list of lines instead of a file object. if not, the code would not work at all as the file object is an iterable.

Comment: @hansaplast I've added the first line match, and at Alex Fung I need all three matches in the second line. It contains a URL and only the first string  and the third string (last string on the line) will always be where I expect it to be.

Comment: @AlexFung f is readlines(file) and the file can either be plaintext or gzipped.

Comment: @Sina I don't see why the code doesn't work... Mind to provide us with the sample input ?

Comment: Working on sample input, but it might be difficult to provide due workplace rules.
The code can break on lines totally unrelated to the matching, and errors related to indexes being out of range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133613/discussion-between-alex-fung-and-sina).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very unclear what it is you really want, but after some guessing - could this be what you want?

> 2016-12-30 11:02:12 DEBUG[ispatcher-18269] ab.talk.this.api.Api - http://hostname:19991/trapeze?session_id=176764&manager_event=old&apostrophe=2341231231234&_operation=doc 3da48a90-0f4f-4eb3-a241-94a1f05b891b requesting:
>
> bla bla bla
>
> bla bla bla
>
> bla bla bla
>
> A-Topeka-Firesale: *132*12345*2123456789#

In the text above you want to match the last line. (You've only given a regex, so I made one up matching the criteria.) Finding that line will lead you to the first line, matching `http://hostname:19991/trapeze?`, `manager_event=old` and `requesting:` in that order, but not directly after one another.

If I'm guessing correctly, this regex

```
(http://hostname:19991/trapeze.*?manager_event=old.*?requesting:).*?A-Topeka-Firesale\:\s\*132\*\d{2,5}\*[23]\d{9}\#
```

should (could) do it for you. It captures the first (complete) line, which is what I understand is what you're after. (You haven't specified if it's something spcific you're after in it, like `session_id`, or whatever, but that could be "targeted" directly of course.)

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MK0hpw/1).

Note that the e**x**ample uses the extended flag to allow splitting the regex up to (somewhat) improve readability, and the **s**ingle line flag to have `.` match line feeds.

Comment: Your made up regex is amazingly accurate. Sorry about the lack of clarity. I'm trying to match log lines where what I am after is on different lines. I know that once I find a log line matching `A-Topeka-Firesale: *132*12345*2123456789#`, then when I go backward in the file, about three or four lines above, I will find another line ending with `'requesting:'` or `'requesting: \n'` which will also contain a URL string `http://hostname:19991/trapeze`, and also in that URL string `manager_event=old` must appear(beginning, ending or middle of the URL, position is never certain).

Comment: Then from the line with the URL string, I need to be able to pull out the beginning timestamp, and two other strings: `apostrophe=2341231231234` and `_operation=doc`.

Comment: [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/MK0hpw/2). It captures the `apostrophe` and the `_operation` (group 1 and 2). Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes but the positive look ahead doesn't work for me.  The regex101.com query times out too. I can get matches when I use `(http://hostname:19991/trapeze.*?manager_event=old.*?requesting:)` but there is zero output when I use `(http://hostname:19991/trapeze.*?manager_event=old.*?requesting:).*?A-Topeka-Firesale\:\s\*132\*\d{2,5}\*[23]\d{9}\#`. 
In the form:
`for each, line in enumerate(f):
     trapeze_match = re.search(r'(http:\/\/hostname\:19991\/trapeze.*?manage\_event\=old.*?requesting\:).*?A\-Topeka\-Firesale\:', line.decode("cp1252 "))
     if trapeze_match:
     print(line)
`

Comment: Huh... What do you mean the "regex101 query times out"? It doesn't for me :S Anyway... I don't understand why the look-ahead doesn't work if we're talking python. But it was only a feeble attempt to allow some variation in the order of the parameters. If they're always the same you could use something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/MK0hpw/3)... Or?

Comment: Im very grateful for the efforts. Ive also added some sample lines of what I am trying to parse. By timeouts I meant regex101.com prints `"Your expression took too long to finish and was terminated. Please increase the timeout and try again."` when I try to run the queries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133645/discussion-between-sina-and-clasg).

Comment: I think Ive gotten the regex that works:  a variation of `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}).*?http://hostname:19991/trapeze.*?manager_event=old.*?\bapostrophe=([^&]*).*?\b_operation=(\w+).*?requesting:.*?A-Topeka-Firesale: \*132\*.*?\#` (variations are in the `\*132\*.*?\#` group which I can tweak to get the particular regexes I need to group all the data sets  by). This multiline regex  returns me the timestamp, apostrophe data and _operation data as match groups and I've also seen that I have to f.read() the file as a single string object. I wonder if I've missed anything?

Comment: Thanks for all the help ClasG!